# How can we retrieve count of products from database using vue js?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, count, quasar-framework

Working in Vuejs, Laravel and Quasar all together, i made a dashboard for Admin. now i want to find the number of current products, users and orders are saved in a separate table each in mySQL database.
i was not able to do so, and what i understood is that we can do it via `{{products.lenght}}`. is there anyway to do that?
this is where i want to show to show the number of elements:

**EDIT**

These are my codes:

Template:

```
<template>
  <div class="layout-padding ">
    <div class="flex wrap gutter">
      <div class="width-1of3 xl-auto">
      <q-card inline class="q-ma-sm" style="background:#00C851; color:white; padding:20px; margin:10px">
      <q-card-title>
        Products
        <span slot="subtitle">Available products</span>
      </q-card-title>
      <q-card-main>
        <a href='/#/products/index'>Products {{products.length}} </a>
      </q-card-main>
    </q-card>
      </div>
      <div class="width-1of3 sm-auto">
      <q-card inline class="q-ma-sm" style="background:#00C851; color:white; padding:20px; margin:10px">
      <q-card-title>
        Orders
        <span slot="subtitle">Available Orders</span>
      </q-card-title>
      <q-card-main>
        <a href='/admin/products'>Orders</a>
      </q-card-main>
    </q-card>
      </div>
      <div class="width-1of3 sm-auto">
      <q-card inline class="q-ma-sm" style="background:#00C851; color:white; padding:20px; margin:10px">
      <q-card-title>
        Users
        <span slot="subtitle">Current Registered Users</span>
      </q-card-title>
      <q-card-main>
        <a href='/products/users'>Users </a>
      </q-card-main>
    </q-card>
      </div>
        <div class="width-1of3 sm-auto">
      <q-card inline class="q-ma-sm" style="background:#00C851; color:white; padding:20px; margin:10px">
      <q-card-title>
        Categories
        <span slot="subtitle">Available Categories</span>
      </q-card-title>
      <q-card-main>
        <a href='/admin/products'>Categories</a>
      </q-card-main>
    </q-card>
      </div>
    </div>
      <q-card style="background:#33b5e5; color:white; padding:20px; height:250px; margin-top:10px;">
      <q-card-title>
        Categories
        <span slot="subtitle">Current Categories</span>
      </q-card-title>
      <q-card-main>
      </q-card-main>
    </q-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      user: null,
      columns: [
        { name: 'id', label: 'ID', field: 'id', sortable: false, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'category_id', label: 'Cat ID', field: 'category_id', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'product_name', label: 'Name', field: 'product_name', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'product_detail', label: 'Details', field: 'product_detail', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'original_price', label: 'Prev Price', field: 'original_price', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'product_price', label: 'Price', field: 'product_price', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'actions', label: 'Actions', sortable: false, align: 'right' }
      ],
      selected: [],
      loading: false,
      serverPagination: {
        page: 1,
        rowsNumber: 10, // the number of total rows in DB
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        sortBy: 'id',
        descending: true
      },
      serverData: [],
      products: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    request ({ pagination }) {
      // QTable to "loading" state
      this.loading = true
      axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/list/${pagination.page}?rowsPerPage=${pagination.rowsPerPage}&sortBy=${pagination.sortBy}&descending=${pagination.descending}`)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          // updating pagination to reflect in the UI
          this.serverPagination = pagination

          // we also set (or update) rowsNumber
          this.serverPagination.rowsNumber = data.rowsNumber

          // then we update the rows with the fetched ones
          this.serverData = data.rows

          // finally we tell QTable to exit the "loading" state
          this.loading = false
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // there's an error... do SOMETHING
          console.log(error)

          // we tell QTable to exit the "loading" state
          this.loading = false
        })
    },
    destroy (id, rowIndex) {
      this.$q.dialog({
        title: 'Delete',
        message: 'Are you sure to delete ' + name + '?',
        color: 'primary',
        ok: true,
        cancel: true
      }).then(() => {
        axios
          .delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/${id}`)
          .then(() => {
            // this.serverData[rowIndex].id = 'DELETED'
            this.$q.notify({type: 'positive', timeout: 2000, message: 'The product has been deleted.'})
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.$q.notify({type: 'negative', timeout: 2000, message: 'An error has been occured.'})
            console.log(error)
          })
      }).catch(() => {
        // cancel - do nothing?
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // once mounted, we need to trigger the initial server data fetch
    this.request({
      pagination: this.serverPagination,
      filter: this.filter
    })
    axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products')
      .then(response => {
        this.products = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

**Added Image**

This is what i wanted, if someone does not understand the question.

[image: Result of what i wanted]

Comment: how do you get back that data in vue.js side?

Comment: Using `axios.get'('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/list')`

Comment: could you add the whole code please?

Comment: I updated my question and added codes as well.

Comment: so where'e the issue? i see that you're doing it right

Comment: but i do not get the result, its only 0 written there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184973/discussion-between-hefaz-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming a few things here given that you're using Laravel you're probably trying output a JSON response using eloquent.

**web.php**

```
//Assumed Laravel Route For
//http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/list/${pagination.page}?rowsPerPage=${pagination.rowsPerPage}&sortBy=${pagination.sortBy}&descending=${pagination.descending}
Route::get('products/list','ProductController@index');
```

**ProductController.php**

```
class ProductController  {

    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();

        $allProductsWithProductCount = [
            'products' => $products,
            'products_count' => $products->count()
        ];

        return $allProductsWithProductCount;
    }
}
```

What you can do is count the products, or whatever collection you're returning, add it to an array and return the output like above.

**Vue**

```
data () {
    return {
        productCount: null,
    }
}
```

**In Axios Method**

```
axios
.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/list/${pagination.page}?rowsPerPage=${pagination.rowsPerPage}&sortBy=${pagination.sortBy}&descending=${pagination.descending}`)
.then(({ data }) => {
  this.productCount = data.product_count;
})
```

**Vue Template**

`<h1>Product Count: {{productCount}}</h1>`

Comment: I have no idea, now even i can't see the number 0, which i had before, i set all the codes as you said, but still stuck.

Comment: `console.log(data)`

And copy the JSON response into a codepen for me please.

Comment: does it matter, where to put codes in script? i mean where to put productCount: null, ?

Comment: I deleted my answer. thanks for your help. i really wanted to have a right answer for that, so that a user can use it again. and i really did not notice that i can edit your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. Thank you.